# Javascript CryptoJS v3.1.2 AES.encrypt and C# AesManaged output are not same for the same input

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, aes

I am trying to replicate Javascript CryptoJS v3.1.2 AES.encrypt in C#. I have tried AesManaged, RijndaelManaged but not able to replicate same output in C# as javascript produces.
The java script code is as below:

```
var enteredText = "123456";
var _0x6722=["\x75\x37\x47\x75\x35\x70\x6F\x73\x76\x77\x44\x73\x58\x55\x6E\x56\x35\x5A\x61\x71\x34\x67\x3D\x3D","\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65","\x42\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34","\x65\x6E\x63"];
var rkEncryptionKey=CryptoJS[_0x6722[3]][_0x6722[2]][_0x6722[1]](_0x6722[0])        
var _0x283e=["\x35\x44\x39\x72\x39\x5A\x56\x7A\x45\x59\x59\x67\x68\x61\x39\x33\x30\x61\x55\x4B\x32\x77\x3D\x3D","\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65","\x42\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34","\x65\x6E\x63"];
var rkEncryptionIv=CryptoJS[_0x283e[3]][_0x283e[2]][_0x283e[1]](_0x283e[0])
var utf8Stringified = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(enteredText);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(utf8Stringified.toString(), rkEncryptionKey, 
{
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv: rkEncryptionIv
});
var encryptedText = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

This will produce jvYWNkANUAkYOSEbuJxv1w== as output in javascript.
Below is my C# code which I have written for the AES:

```
string result = "";
            try
            {

                byte[] keybyte = Convert.FromBase64String("u7Gu5posvwDsXUnV5Zaq4g==");
                byte[] keyiv = Convert.FromBase64String("5D9r9ZVzEYYgha930aUK2w==");
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123456");
                AesManaged aesManaged = new AesManaged();
                aesManaged.KeySize = 128;
                aesManaged.Key = keybyte;
                aesManaged.BlockSize = 128;
                aesManaged.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                aesManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aesManaged.IV = keyiv;
                AesManaged aesManaged2 = aesManaged;
                string text;
                using (ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(aesManaged.Key, aesManaged.IV))
                {               
                    text = Convert.ToBase64String(cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));                    


                }
                result = text;
            }
            catch { }
```

My C# code is not producing the same output. Please suggest what issue I have in my C#

Comment: Cipher mode mismatch? In javascript there is CBC, in C# there is ECB.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I also have tried using CBC its producing still different output.